# How to know the minimum memory required for a data set and algorithm?

Tags: h2o

I start-up H2O with: `h2o.init(nthreads=-1, max_mem_size="256m")` or `h2o.init(nthreads=2, max_mem_size="6g")`, etc. What I would like to know is the minimum `max_mem_size` I can get away with.

E.g. on my development machine I might be happy to give it 6g, but when I move it to a cloud server, where the cost is often proportional to the memory I request, if I can get away with, say, a 1gb instance, it would be wasteful to be renting an 8gb instance.

I think the memory usage is mainly on the data sets? But is there a way to find out the peak memory that was used by a data set, plus the training of a model on it?